# How can I write a recursive function with let in (in ocaml)

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I have this local function. I have to write it with a `let ... in` because in other case I get a syntax error. How can I do it for not only `before` but `after` too! Let's just say that before looks like this:

```
before = "a/drivers/usb/gadget/.../file"
```

and `after` looks like this:

```
after = "b/drivers/usb/gadget/..../file"`
```

and my rec function looks like this:

```
let rec f (before: string list) : string list =
          begin match Str.split (Str.regexp "/") before  with 
                         | _ ::rest -> out (String.concat "/" rest)
                         | _ -> ()
              end
```

Comment: What is the question (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very hard to understand, but if I have it right: the essence of a function is that you can call it as many times as you like, with different parameters.

```
let sqdist (x0, y0) (x1, y1) =
    let sq a = a * a in
    sq (x1 - x0) + sq (y1 - y0)
```

Here I've defined `sq` as a local function and I'm calling it both for `x1 - x0` and for `y1 - y0`.

**Update:**

It now sounds to me like your function is supposed to process all the elements of a list. This is something you would use `List.map` for in real life. To do your own mapping with recursion, your code would look something like this:

```
let squareEveryInt (list: int list) : int list =
    let rec go l =
        match l with
        | [] -> []
        | n :: rest -> n * n :: go rest
    in
    go list
```

There are many important differences here from your example code. I think the main thing you're missing is a recursive call to your function.

Comment: yes my function "let rec" is local ! even the let rec! so have to just use a let instead of a let rec?

Comment: The use of `rec` depends entirely on whether your function needs to call itself. If it doesn't need to call itself, you don't need to have `rec`. Your example code doesn't call itself, so I suspect you can just leave off the `rec`. But I doubt this is your basic problem, as it wouldn't hurt to specify `rec` either.

Comment: the thing is my exepmle suppose to parse a line, delete the first element of the line, printf the rest of it (with concatinating the elements with "/" ) ,so i think it's a rec function because it calls it self everytime and do it over and over again!! maybe i'm wrong! but this is how i see it!! i am wrong?

Comment: OK, now it sounds like your function *does* call itself, in order to process all the elements of a list. So then, yes, you need to specify `let rec`.

Comment: ok thank you :) but why i have this weird syntax error! i thaught that it was right (syntaxily at least)

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. You'd have to show what your code looks like and what error you get.

Comment: let out x = Printf.printf " %s \n" x 
let _ = try
 while true do
     let line = input_line stdin in                       begin match (Str.split (Str.regexp " ") line) with ..blahblahblah
 | ["diff"; _; before; after] -> out before; out after;
let f (before: string list) : ( string list )  = 
     let rec go l =
     ( match  Str.split (Str.regexp "/") before  with 
                         | _ ::rest -> out (String.concat "/" rest)
                         | _ -> () ) in 
                    go list
    ........| _ -> ()

         end
       done
  with
      End_of_file -> ()